# Parse JSON LIST in a JSON LIST PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pljson

I'm working with PLJSON and ORACLE ,I have a JSON like this

```
{
  "DATA": {
    "FROM_DATA": [
      {
        "COL": "",
        "ROW": "",
        "GET_DATA": [{"0":"df"}],
        "SAVE_DATE": [{"2":"ar"}]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm able to parse FROM_DATA and get COL and ROW value but I can't parse GET_DATA and SAVE_DATA array.

This is my code :

```
objet_json :=json(i_json.get('DATA'));  

 JSONDATA:= json_list(objet_json.get('FROM_DATA'));  

JSONGETDATA:= json_list(objet_json .get('GET_DATA'));  (1)
 JSONSAVEDATA:= json_list(objet_json .get('SAVE_DATE'));  (2)
```

But I got an error on (1) and (2) :

```
ora-30625 method dispatch on null self argument is disallowed
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? If you are using Oracle 12c or later then it has built-in JSON support and you do not need to use a 3rd-party package.

Comment: @MT0 i'm using:  Oracle Database 11g

Comment: Have you tried `json_list(JSONDATA.get('GET_DATA'));` ? As "GET_DATA" is sub element of "FROM_DATA" and not of "DATA"...

Answer (score 0):

`DATA.FROM_DATA` is an array containing a single element; it is not an object.

Looking at the [examples in the PLJSON git repository](https://github.com/pljson/pljson/blob/master/examples/ex8.sql), you need to use `.get(1)` to get the first element of the array:

```sql
DECLARE
  i_json pljson := pljson(
    '{
      "DATA": {
        "FROM_DATA": [
          {
            "COL": "",
            "ROW": "",
            "GET_DATA": [{"0":"df"}],
            "SAVE_DATE": [{"2":"ar"}]
          }
        ]
      }
    }'
  );
  objet_json   pljson;
  JSONARRAY    pljson_list;
  JSONDATA     pljson;
  JSONGETDATA  pljson_list;
  JSONSAVEDATA pljson_list;
BEGIN
  objet_json   := pljson(i_json.get('DATA'));  
  JSONARRAY    := pljson_list(objet_json.get('FROM_DATA'));  
  JSONDATA     := pljson(JSONARRAY.get(1));
  JSONGETDATA  := pljson_list(JSONDATA.get('GET_DATA'));
  JSONSAVEDATA := pljson_list(JSONDATA.get('SAVE_DATE'));

  JSONGETDATA.print;
  JSONSAVEDATA.print;
END;
/
```

*(Note: the objects/packages have the `pl` prefix as db<>fiddle does not allow creating synonyms; you should be able to remove those prefixes if your implementation has the appropriate synonyms created.)*

outputs:

> ```
> [{
>   "0" : "df"
> }]
> [{
>   "2" : "ar"
> }]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7bd6428ac24b179b59d9752d7974c52d)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop over the elements:

```sql
objet_json := json(i_json.get('DATA'));  
JSONDATA   := json_list(objet_json.get('FROM_DATA'));  

FOR i IN JSONDATA.FIRST..JSONDATA.LAST LOOP
  JSONGETDATA  := json_list(JSONDATA(i).get('GET_DATA'));
  JSONSAVEDATA := json_list(JSONDATA(i).get('SAVE_DATE'));
END LOOP;
```

Perhaps you have to add some additional constructor calls:

```sql
objet_json := json(i_json.get('DATA'));  
JSONDATA   := json_list(objet_json.get('FROM_DATA'));  

FOR i IN JSONDATA.FIRST..JSONDATA.LAST LOOP
  JSONGETDATA  := json_list(json(JSONDATA(i)).get('GET_DATA'));
  JSONSAVEDATA := json_list(json(JSONDATA(i)).get('SAVE_DATE'));
END LOOP;
```